# Connecting to Oracle DB hosted on Windows 8.1 Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, database, azure, oracle, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8.1 vm created on azure, it has 14 GB of memory and 200 some GB storage. I have installed Oracle with a templated database onto it. Everything is fine with the installation and I can use `sqlplus` to do sql commands and such. The listener is also on.

But, I am having troubles connecting to the VM from a c# app. I have opened the `1521` ports as shown in [this document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-creating-oracle-database-virtual-machine/) near the bottom. Is there something else I can do/try or haven't done to allow me to connect to the database from my PC?

I also am trying to ping the public ip address supplied but have not been able to do so, any help there would be nice too. I have followed the steps [here](http://blogs.biztalk360.com/windows-azure-virtual-machines-virtual-network-may-not-ping-automatically/)

Update:

I have tried to connect to the database from PLSQL Developer, here is the listing I put in my TNSNames.ora file (I have also tried the public IP address instead of the [myapp].cloudapp.net):

```
AzureDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [myapp].cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PLDB)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Why do you use a client OS to host a DB server?

Comment: I have $150 in azure credit per month and to run it on a Windows 8.1 VM keeps me from having to pay anything extra per month.

Answer (score 1):

Can you connect to the DB with something like Oracle SQL developer? I would verify that you can hit the DB remotely first and then troubleshoot your C#.  Could be drivers or not having the right driver (32 vs 64 bit).

Comment: I have tried with `PL/SQL Developer` and cannot connect to it.

Comment: Verify you are actually on 1521.     To find the current setting for the Oracle Management agent port, search for EMD_URL in the ORACLE_BASE/ORACLE_HOME/host_sid/sysman/config/emd.properties file.

To change the Oracle Management Agent HTTP port, use the emca -reconfig ports command:
emca -reconfig ports -AGENT_PORT 1831